# How to automatically remove space before punctuation

Tags: python, regex

For example:
"This is some text . This is some text"

should be

"This is some text. This is some text"

We can use replase but replacing ' .' with '.', but it's not a good approach. Please let me know if you have any other idea which is generalised for any punctuation.

Comment: Try using regex.

Comment: Why your method wouldn't be a good method? I couldn't imagine an alternative situation where it would be not a good idea.

Comment: @MSH, It would be for dots only, but, as the title says, it might be other punctuation marks too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry I'm on mobile but it would be something like this:

```
import re
print(re.sub(r'\s(?=[\.,:;])', "", yourstring))
```